# Post full form data to a service in Angular

Tags: angularjs, forms, submit

I have a form that contains a lot of fields and I want to post all the form fields to a service using a post method. But I would like to send the whole form object and not to write one property by one. If I try to post the object that contains all my fields $scope.formData it also contains all the angular stuff inside like errors. What I need is a collection of field names and values. How can I achieve this with minimum coding?

Edit:
I ended up writing my own function:

```
function getAngularFormFields(form) {
var dictionary = { form: {} };
for (var key in form) {
    if (form.hasOwnProperty(key) && !key.indexOf('$') == 0) {
        dictionary.form[key] = form[key].$modelValue;
    }
}

return dictionary;
```

}

Comment: Well, what have you tried? A simple approach would be to grab the form object (make a copy) and remove the "stuff inside like errors". I don't think you have a way of doing this without looping  in some manner. But why not just use the default POST provided by your browser?

Comment: I am looking for the built in functionality that will do that. I do not want to write a looping method if I do not have to. But if there is not one I will write it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you need to post a form you could just use the default method provided by your browser. This will send the form data, via POST, to your URL.

```
<form action="yourUrlHere" method="POST">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I have to use ng-form, as form element is declared outside my control and contains a lot of other elements I do not need. Can this be done through ng-form?